# Disabling keyboard irq receives so many enter keys

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I was trying to write a sample code to test `disable_irq` and `enable_irq`. As the IRQ Number for Keyboard is 1, I wrote the following code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
static int test_interrupt_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"%s: In init\n", __func__);
    disable_irq(1);
    msleep(5*1000);
    enable_irq(1);
    return 0;
}

static void test_interrupt_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"%s: In exit\n", __func__);
}

module_init(test_interrupt_init);
module_exit(test_interrupt_exit);
```

The output behavior is wierd, it disables the keyboard, but a lot of enter keys are automatically being pressed. How is sending the Enter keys to the Linux Kernel

Comment: A better question might be: after you've deliberately ruined everything, how can `msleep()` work without a timer IRQ to let kernel know you should stop sleeping?

Comment: I have only disabled keyboard IRQ not timer irq

Comment: Have you? Keyboard is likely to be a USB device where USB controller uses MSI or IO APIC (and not IRQ 1). If it is an ancient computer (with a real PS/2 keyboard) then you probably press "enter" to start your module and the GUI (or maybe keyboard driver) probably starts emulating "key repeat" when it sees "enter key pressed" until it sees the "enter key released" that you disabled.

Comment: irq number 1 is for i8042 which is the keyboard integrated in my laptop

Comment: I connected a USB Keyboard to my Laptop, pressing keys still increases the count in irq 1 . Observed the behavior in "watch -n 0.1 cat /proc/interrupts"

Comment: I tried loading the module from cron job instead of typing insmod and pressing enter. With cron job, there were no enter keys being pressed, so you were correct, as there was no key release after typing insmod, it continuously emulated enter key until the interrupts were enabled again